# Laravel Mariadb empty strings and null constraints

Tags: php, laravel-4, mariadb

I recently had an issue with an old Laravel 4 app.

I was trying to set up a local dev environment and in some cases, things were failing with a not null constraint.

After a bit of digging, I found this was down to MariaDB treating empty strings as nulls.

It seems that I could switch the [compatibility option](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-portability.php) MDB2_PORTABILITY_EMPTY_TO_NULL,  however, I can't see where I would do this. There doesn't seem to be a server variable or php variable I can set. Laravel doesn't seem to support such options on the connect string.

Where would I stop empty being treated as null?

I believe this is the option causing the issue.

> MDB2_PORTABILITY_EMPTY_TO_NULL
>   Convert empty strings values to null in data in and output. Needed because Oracle considers empty strings to be null, while most other DBMSs know the difference between empty and null.

I'm inserting records with empty strings, and they are failing with null not allowed error.

Comment: Show us the statement that lead you to say "treating empty strings as nulls".

Comment: And, which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: "Oracle considers..." that refers to the Oracle DB, not MariaDB, nor MySQL.

Comment: "You control which portability modes are enabled by using the portability configuration option. Configuration options are set via factory() and setOption()."

Comment: I thought it was a mariadb setting for oracle compatibility

Comment: It sounds like "mdb2", which would be 'above' MariaDB and 'below' Laravel.  (I am guessing.)